# PuLP not printing output on IPython cell

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, mathematical-optimization, pulp

I am using [PuLP](https://pythonhosted.org/PuLP/) and IPython/Jupyter Notebook for a project.

I have the following cell of code:

```
import pulp
model = pulp.LpProblem('Example', pulp.LpMinimize)
x1 = pulp.LpVariable('x1', lowBound=0, cat='Integer')
x2 = pulp.LpVariable('x2', lowBound=0, cat='Integer')

model += -2*x1 - 3*x2 
model += x1 + 2*x2 <= 7
model += 2*x1 + x2 <= 7
model.solve(pulp.solvers.COIN(msg=True))
```

When I execute the cell, the output is simply:

```
1
```

When I look at the terminal running the Notebook server, I can see the output of the solver (in this case: COIN). The same happens if a change the *model.solve* argument to

```
model.solve(pulp.solvers.PULP_CBC_CMD(msg=True))
```

or

```
model.solve(pulp.solvers.PYGLPK(msg=True))
```

However, when I use the Gurobi Solver, with the line

```
model.solve(pulp.solvers.GUROBI(msg=True))
```

the output of the solver is displayed on the Notebook cell, which is the behavior I want. In fact, I would be happy with any free solver printing its output directly on the Notebook cell.

I could not find directions on how to approach this issue in PuLP documentation. Any help would be appreciated. I am also curious to know if someone else gets this behavior.

I am using Linux Mint, 64 Bits, IPython 4.0.0 and PuLP 1.6.0.

Comment: When you call `model.solve(pulp.solvers.COIN(msg=True))` in ipython notebook it's equivalent to `print model.solve(pulp.solvers.COIN(msg=True))`, that's why you have 1 as output. Call your IPython/Jupyter Notebook from the terminal, after you extract this script in the notebook look at the terminal's output, solvers message should be there. If you need solver's output in your notebook, you can paste it as string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @serge_k. If I understood it correctly, I have to do it manually, then. Is there a simple way to redirect the output? I want this behavior because I am preparing a course using the Notebook, however, I wouldn't like the audience to focus on the technicalities of the Notebook itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%%python` cell magic to print terminal's output.

```
%%python
import pulp
model = pulp.LpProblem('Example', pulp.LpMinimize)
x1 = pulp.LpVariable('x1', lowBound=0, cat='Integer')
x2 = pulp.LpVariable('x2', lowBound=0, cat='Integer')

model += -2*x1 - 3*x2 
model += x1 + 2*x2 <= 7
model += 2*x1 + x2 <= 7

model.solve(pulp.solvers.COIN(msg=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but for anyone still looking for a solution...

Create a file called `monkeypatch.py` and put it in the same directory as your notebooks

Paste the following into it, and save

```
from pulp import PULP_CBC_CMD, LpProblem

original_solve_method = LpProblem.solve

def solve(prob):
    solver = PULP_CBC_CMD(logPath=r'log.txt', msg=False)
    original_solve_method(prob, solver=solver)
    with open('log.txt', 'r') as f:
        print(f.read())

LpProblem.solve = solve
```

Then in your notebook insert the line

```
import monkeypatch
```

near the top.

It will overwrite the solve method, so that it writes the logfile to "log.txt" and then reads in this file and displays it inside the notebook.